Will soft copper pipe deform under vacuum
I have a need to run cooling water through a pipe into a vacuum chamber. The vacuum chamber is at 0.7 to 10 pascal. This pipe will be filled with water. This water will be at a very low PSI, almost 1 ATM.

Is there a proper term/search term for understanding how thick a pipe's wall needs to be in order to not break under a vacuum? Do you know of any good charts/tables?

Do you think that the soft copper pipe will break/leak into the vacuum chamber?

Do you have any other, cost effective, suggestions for pluming water into a vacuum chamber?


Best Regards
EDIT:
First, note 1 ATM = 15 PSI

It looks like 'differential pressure' is the search term.
It looks like soft copper refrigerator pipe which is rated at > 30 PSI should be fine.
N/A

Thank you all!

So how effective do you think heat transfer will be in a vacuum?

Hi Mike, the pipe will be pushing water into and out of a cooling plate which it will be physically touching. Since there will be physical contact, the heat transfer should be pretty good.   I know that a good grade of refrigerator soft copper pipe can withstand 100's of PSI while at 1 atm. I just don't know how it will do at a lower pressure. Any ideas?

The pressure differential is going to be about 15 psi which is pretty low.

@jsotola, I agree. I was mostly just addressing Solar Mike's trolling and trying to kindly point him back to the question asked in the initial question :)

From the perspective of the pipe, it's pressurized with the difference between external and internal pressure.  So if your pipe is pressurized to 1 ATM relative to the room then it'll be pressurized to 2 ATM inside a full vacuum.
If the pipe is rated for 30 psi -- you're fine.
